# What's different between Command N or T on Safari?

Tags: safari, tabs

On Safari, when I type <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> or <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>, both shortcuts do same thing: Create a new tab and move to it.

What's the difference?

When should I use <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> and <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the behavior in full screen Safari and they are both the same. When in windowed mode <kbd>⌘CMD</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> opens new window.

If you want to open new window in full screen you have to press <kbd>⌘CMD</kbd><kbd>⌥ALT</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>. This creates new full screen Safari window in a new Space.